# Can't open custom screen due to insufficient rights message

Tags: acumatica

I customized the Cases screen by adding a new button on the Activities tab's grid toolbar.  I'm using PXRedirectRequiredException to try to open a new custom screen I created.  This throws the insufficient rights message to my new screen's graph.  In the Access Rights by Role and by Screen, I made sure that my new screen was granted permission to both Administrator and EMPLOYEE, but I still get this message and can't open the new screen.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fernando in the answer above, I opened the new screen by URL, which uncovered the real error. My screen's TypeName was wrong because I had renamed the class, and An ASP.NET error displayed this fact.  Once I fixed the TypeName, the screen opened. The insufficient rights message was an incorrect error and a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

This error could be caused by a missing site map definition.
Have you added your custom screen to the site map? Try to access it directly by entering the page ID in the URL.
Example: http://localhost/[InstanceName]/Main?ScreenId=AA101000
If you are redirected to the home (page 00000000), there is an error with the site map for this page.

Comment: Although this wasn't the solution, it did lead me to one, so thank you.  By opening my new screen by URL it uncovered the real error.